# Cannot migrate Devise Token Auth project

Tags: ruby, devise

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<ActiveRecord::Migration:0x00000001fe0fa0>
```

This pops up whenever I try running rake:db migrate

[I've been following this guide word for word](http://www.developingandrails.com/2015/02/api-authentication-with-devisetokenauth.html)

I'm having tremendous trouble interpreting the stacktrace as well
[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/pE1n8XRx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unbelievable but it's all about a typo (or something like that?) at the migration file which is generated by the generator.

See the `..._devise_token_auth_create_users.rb` file at `db/migrate` directory. You will see that at the first line of the migration file there is an odd `[4.2]` string.

```
class DeviseTokenAuthCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
```

Just remove that odd `[4.2]` string from that line and voila.

However, I must admit that, this experience made me think twice about using this gem at my project.